# Succes with compiling Error JVM Oracle Database Move Data

Tags: java, oracle, jvm

I have a Data in a specific folder. I only know the id. But the name of the data contain more then an ID, because of that I am using "listFiles". For security reason only the database can enter the file system, because of that I want to upload the java class into my oracle. But my Oracle DB always says that it success compiling with Error and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED MOVEFILE as `import java.io.*`;
public class MOVEFILE {
/**
 * Eigentliche Methode zum Verschieben
 */
public static int moveFile(String orgPath, String gewPfad, String dateiID) {
    File folder = new File(orgPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File folder, String name){return name.toLowerCase().contains(dateiID);}});
    String orgDatei = listOfFiles[0].toString();
    File org = new File(orgDatei);
    File gew = new File(gewPfad);
    if (!org.exists())
        return 0;
    if (gew.exists())
        return 0;
    if (copyFile(orgDatei, gewPfad) == 1)
        if (deleteFile(orgDatei) == 1)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I have methods `copyFile` and `deleteFile`. When I compile them without `moveFile` it compiles successfully.

Can you help me? Sorry for my bad english. If you have any question I will answer them as soon as I can. Thank you :)

Comment: Try with `final String dateiID` instead of  `String dateiID`.

Comment: copyFile() and deleteFile() methods are static ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Berger got it right in the comments, I think.

You cannot reference `dateiID` in the anonymous inner class you define for `listOfFiles`, unless you make `dateiID` `final`.

Also, you don't need single quotes around the `import` line.

You could have discovered this for yourself by asking the database what the problem was, like so:

```
select * 
from dba_errors 
where name = 'MOVEFILE' 
order by sequence;
```